# What's the meaning of 'otherwise' in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What's the meaning of *otherwise* in this sentence?

> Even a fifteen-minute burst of light in **otherwise** sustained
>   darkness can reset an animal's circadian rhythm.

Comment: Have you looked up the word in a dictionary? Please edit your question to add what that told you, and what remains unclear to you.

Comment: I've looked up the word in Longman dictionary, but I didn't get the meaning of that word in context. Hguler answered my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What it means is that darkness is sustained **except** for the fifteen-minute burst of light.  If the word "otherwise" were left out, there would be potential confusion because darkness is not being sustained during the fifteen-minute burst of light.